# SSIS XMl processing

Tags: xml, ssis, etl

For my job I do very big imports of (product) data. Recently we started using SSIS and it sure works better then custom .net import tools. Still after 3 projects we figured out it's more efficient to use an scripttask with c# xpath and sql statements then to use XML source and merge joins in a dataflow.

Problems with a dataflow

- Sometimes the xml cannot read from a variable
- It depends too much on a fixed definition of XML (the xsd needs to    be known)
- When definitions change a whole needs to be altered
- To specific type handling; UINT and INT arn't the same
- Not easy to debug and step through as C# code

Can anyone share their SSIS XML import stories

Comment: I used the xml source component with SSIS 2005 successfully. There are a few quirks with how the component processes paths but I worked around them. Apart from this I had no problems with variables. Dependency on XSD was a good thing in my case as I really wanted data to be validate. If it doesn't conform then there is something wrong with our xml extractor and it has to be fixed. Our definitions changed rarely so was not a problem for us. Haven't come acrod int/uint issues as we mostly imported strings. And as for debbuging, to be honest there is not too much to debug there: meet in mince out

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Still I much rather work with script task. And I value your comment on only importing strings. Maybe this should be the rule. Only import values as strings, only convert if it's needed

Comment: can you describe in more details your experience ? I'm considerning using SSIS for transforming several xml format files into my app's DB. Now we have just custom coded tool, parsing xml and making a lot of insert/updates - it is really inefficient and i'm thinking how to improve it

Comment: SSIS is crap - it works on some servers and fails on others for no apparent reason. I replaced our SSIS packade with an exe, so I don't have to put up with it any more.

Answer (score 0):

I work "all the way" with XML in SQL Server and mainly it is import feature in some of my projects.I do not use SSIS XML source because of limitation of XML structure. As example, it is not possible to import data from "Excel XML", where not only data but column names are as values. To prepare this kind of import, i use TSQL code. Maybe for this example you can use third-party components, but not all customers want to pay for that.))

Answer (score 0):

You could try experimenting with some of the 3rd party components on CodeProject, or if your C#/VB skills are up for it, then consider rolling up your sleeves and writing a source script component to shred the xml using a SAX parser. This will allow the data flow to stream over the XML instead of loading the entire thing into a DOM.